# How to compare values of two maps in Erlang. [My solution does not return any value]

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

```
compare(M1, M2) -> 
    Map1 = maps:from_list(M1)
    Map2 = maps:from_list(M2)
    Keys1 = maps:keys(Map1)
    lists:foreach(fun(I) -> 
                  V1 = maps:get(I, Map1)
                  V2 = maps:get(I, Map2)
                  if V1 < V2 -> true;
                  true -> false end
                  end, Keys1).
```

This is my approach. But I always get ok in the output. 
What am I missing here?
Conditions: keys will be same in both the maps. 
for example, this is how I will execute

```
compare([{p1, 1},{p2, 3}], [{p1, 4}, {p2, 5}]
```

- Values in M1 should be less than M2 and if not then return false.

Comment: `lists:foreach` always returns `ok`. Try changing it to `lists:map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`lists:foreach` ignores the value that passed function returns. You can use `lists:all/2` here, returning if `V1 < V2` from the passed function. If all `V1` are less than `V2`, it'll return `true`, otherwise `false`:

```
lists:all(fun(I) -> 
    V1 = maps:get(I, Map1)
    V2 = maps:get(I, Map2)
    V1 < V2
  end, Keys1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you may try to use lists comprehensions (in case you want to compare lists instead of maps)

```
List1 = [{p1, 1},{p2, 3}],
List2 = [{p1, 4}, {p2, 5}],

Result = [Val < Val2 || {Key, Val} <- List1, {Key2, Val2} <- List2].
```

Result will be:

```
[true,true,true,true]
```